# Cross-referencing values from a reference table with fuzzy inputs

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I've got a Microsoft Access database with several tables. I've thrown 2 of those into an Excel file to simplify my work, but either an Access or Excel solution can be used for this. Below are examples of the data that needs to be manipulated, but in those records there's a lot of other columns and information.

I've got Table 1 (Input Table):

```
|      Bank       | Reference |
|-----------------|-----------|
| Chase Bank LLC  |           |
| JPMorgan Chase  |           |
| Chase           |           |
| Bank of America |           |
| Bank of America |           |
| Wells Fargo     |           |
```

The Reference column is empty. I want to fill it based on the reference table, which contains the IDs that would go into the Reference column.

Table 2 (Reference Table):

```
|      Bank       |    ID     |
|-----------------|-----------|
| Chase Bank      |     1     |
| Bank of America |     2     |
| Wells Fargo     |     3     |
```

So the solution would fill the "Reference" column like this:

```
|      Bank       | Reference |
|-----------------|-----------|
| Chase Bank LLC  |     1     |
| JPMorgan Chase  |     1     |
| Chase           |     1     |
| Bank of America |     2     |
| Bank of America |     2     |
| Wells Fargo     |     3     |
```

Since this is taken from a database's table, these aren't really ordered records. The purpose of this is to create a relationship in an already-existing database that didn't have those relationships set up.

Comment: Fuzzy data matching is a common topic and there is no simple generic solution. Your question is too broad. JOIN tables and UPDATE where there is good match. Case-by-case review of remaining unmatched records to populate Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a join between the 2 text fields, in an Update query, will provide a write of the ID for those records that exactly match.

there is no technology/option for the non matching; you can only apply some creative designs...  for instance the chase bank does match for the first 10 characters... so for the non matched you could set up a temp table with a new field that is Left(fieldname,10)...join on this new field to get the ID into the temp table - - and then do a 2nd Update query to move the ID again finally using the full name

Comment: Thanks, I think this is as good as the answer can get. From what I've gathered, fuzzy data matching is lot more of a general problematic concept in Computer Science, so my question is focusing on something that is not fully answerable yet.